# Where/When to free PWideChars sent to external DLL

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

I'm allocating memory for several PWideChar on my main executable file

```
var
  pwcValor: PWideChar;
begin
  pwcValor := AllocMem( sizeof(WideChar) * Succ(Length(pValor)));
  StringToWideChar(pValor, pwcValor, Succ(Length(pValor)));
  pMetodo(pCodigo, pCodigoParametro, pwcValor);
```

All of these variables are sent over to an external DLL using late binding. I have some questions about this situation to avoid memory leaks.

- Where (on my exe or my dll) should I call the FreeMem on these variables?
- Do I need to call FreeMem on these variables?
- When can I (or should I) call FreeMem on these variables?

If I call them inside the external DLL (which is also mine), I get Access Violations when I try to Unload from memory the DLL library. 
Tks

**EDIT**

Something I forgot to ask. And the other way around? I have so return parameters from my DLL to the EXE, so the PWideChars are allocated on the DLL. So, I would have to free them on the DLL, right? But I'll probably still be using them on the EXE. Must I pre-allocate on the EXE, send to the DLL the pointer, and have it filled in the DLL in these cases? Or just make a copy on the EXE of the returned parameter, so I can free it safely on the DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately that depends on the design of the DLLs you use. However, I would say that if not documented otherwise it is safe to free the resources as soon as the DLL function returns. I would even suggest that you should do it. Anyway you must do it to avoid memory leaks.

Regarding the last sentence, a DLL and the invoking EXE eventhough they both be Delphi code, they use different memory managers, so you cannot in a DLL free memory allocated in the EXE.

Comment: @PA, I have to keep the pointers of all allocated PWideChars sent to the DLL so they can be freed later, right?
Another question I forgot to ask... and the other way around? I have some return PWideChar that are allocated on the DLL that I return to the EXE. I can't free them in the DLL, since they will still be in use by the EXE. Tks

Comment: EXE code can't free mem allocated by a DLL. If you **must** alloc mem in the DLL then you must free it in the DLL, maybe in a function callable by the EXE when done with the returned mem. However, I would try to avoid DLL allocs, and always use mem allocated by the EXE

Answer (score 2):

*Regarding to freeing:*

There are different possible solutions here:

- Your exe can allocate buffer, which then would be filled by dll;
- Your dll can export one more function, say FreeString. Exe should call it every time it has finished with the string;
- You can use simple WideString type. This type of strings use system memory manager which is the same for exe and dll.

Personally I recommend you the last option.

Comment: There's a general recommendation against using the Delphi String type for passing strings to DLLs. There is no problem using WideStrings across DLLs?

Comment: Yes, WideStrings are safe. Even more, in C++ this type of strings also exist, it is named BSTR.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Delphi string variable and are using D2009 or later so that PChar maps to PWideChar then you can just call your function with `pMetodo(pCodigo, pCodigoParametro, PChar(pValor))`.  Then inside your DLL, you take a copy of the string by declaring a string variable and simply assigning to the string.  For example the DLL code would look like this:

```
procedure pMetodo(pwcValor: PChar);
var
  pValor: string;
begin
  pValor := pwcValor;
  ...
end;
```

The code as you have it is quite unnecessarily complex.  Doing it the way I suggest avoids having to use any explicit memory allocation routines.  If you want to write C code then why use Delphi!!  ;-)

If you wanted to be more explicit then you could write PWideChar rather than PChar.

Comment: you can still write PWideChar(WideString(...)) and avoid the allocation